# Google pubsub flow control

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, google-client

I'm trying to implement a service which consumes a google pubsub subscription at its own pace. By that, I mean I need fine control on when I need to consume messages i.e get a batch of messages, pause for a while, do not get more than X messages...

Using google client libraries I did not find a way to do it as the MessageReceiver is running in its own thread and I don't have any control on what exactly happens.

Basically, being able to consume messages in a synchronous way should solve my issue.

Do you know how I can use the google client libs synchronously ? Or is there another way in the API I missed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try using [`setFlowControlSettings`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setFlowControlSettings-com.google.api.gax.batching.FlowControlSettings-) when you build your subscriber. In particular, you can use [`setMaxOutstandingElementCount`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.4.1/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/batching/FlowControlSettings.Builder.html#setMaxOutstandingElementCount-java.lang.Long-) or [`setMaxOutstandingRequestBytes`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.4.1/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/batching/FlowControlSettings.Builder.html#setMaxOutstandingRequestBytes-java.lang.Long-) to limit the messages sent to your MessageReceiver. When you have enough messages outstanding, i.e., messages for which you have not called `Ack()` or `Nack()`, to exceed these limits, then your MessageReceiver will not be called until messages have been acked or nacked.

Comment: I agree with you, and I tried it earlier today, but that doesn't solve all my issues. For instance, How do I pause the retrieval of messages without doing stopAsync? I also need to do stuff like I need at max X messages in a timeframe of Y seconds maximum.

Comment: If you need that more exacting level of control, then you'll need to use the gRPC or REST libraries directly. The [service APIs overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview) has some more info.

Comment: That's the route I wanted to avoid, but I guess I'm out of options.

Comment: This is only per client, right? It wouldn't share that limit across subscriptions on multiple clients? Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: The limit is not shared across clients, no, they are placed per client. It is not possible to share the limit across multiple subscriptions on multiple clients.

Comment: You can look into using Dataflow and use windowing and then eventually send it to pubsub.